Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls TreeView not working in modern browsers
I am using Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls TreeView.cs only in my .net application, this is working fine in IE(compatability mode), now I am trying to make my application to work in latest browsers as well, now TreeView is not working properly and the rootcause is, it is using TreeView.htc which is not supported by modern browsers
output.Write("<?XML:NAMESPACE PREFIX=TVNS />\n<?IMPORT NAMESPACE=TVNS IMPLEMENTATION=\"" 
            + AddPathToFilename("treeview.htc") + "\" />");

Is there any equivalent .js file ? so that I will replace TreeView.htc with TreeView.js
